# How to disable a form used in php?

Tags: php

I have two forms named form1 and form2 in a php page. I have to disable the form2 on page load and enable it after clicked the submit button of form1.. please help me..

" method="post">

    Enter Students Register Number:
    
  

  " method="post" >
   "text box to show details"

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. Do you already have some code you have written that we can help you debug or evaluate? If not, read up on the jQuery docs for .submit() listeners on a form as well as event.preventDefault().

Comment: well, if you can clarify what "disable" means for you... but you probably want to use javascript here, since all the action/interaction seems to happen after the page is loaded (and by extension the php interpreter has done its work)

Comment: I'm willing to bet what you are looking for is not "PHP" related, rather it is a javascript question.

Comment: if submitting the form refreshes the page - it can be a php question :)

Comment: Please take a minute and study the [Markdown editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). If you expect us to help then you should be at least be so kind to provide a proper question.

Comment: [I think this may be what you're looking for](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a conceptualization to give you an idea on how you could accomplish this, I haven't tested it.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" onSubmit="javascript:enableNextForm(this);">
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2">
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="submit2" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

<script>
    function enableNextForm(form)
    {
        // data in `form1` can be accessed through `form` variable

        // target second form and enable submit button
        var s = document.getElementById('submit2').disabled = false;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```